# Frequency of oscillation in Simple U-Tube Manometer by Energy Method

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, frequency

**Force Balance Method**

By balancing accelerating and restoring Force, it's easy to find the angular frequency $\omega$

Restoring Force= Weight of the extra height of liquid column$$=\rho*Area*2x*g$$
Inertial Force=Mass*Acceleration $$=\rho*A*l*g*x*\omega^2$$
Solving,
$$\omega^2=\frac{2g}{l}$$

**Energy method**
I am not able to understand the concept behind potential energy as explained in this solution[image].
Kinetic energy is considered for whole system while potential energy is only for half portion above the equilibrium level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential energy is always measured with respect to some reference level. In this case, when the liquid column is in equilibrium, so that the two levels are at the same height, we can say that its potential energy is zero. Displacing the column by a distance $x$ from the equilibrium level raises the system's potential energy by $\rho A g x^2$ as given in the question.

The reference level of the potential energy can be set to any convenient value. In this case there is a clear physical motivation for setting the potential energy of the equilibrium state to zero, but you could add any constant onto the potential energy without changing the physics.

Comment: If we consider the whole system, isn't the potential energy change twice than mentioned above because there is a fall in potential energy of left portion and equal gain in right?

Comment: Take a look at the picture. The arm on the left drops by $x$ from the eqm value, and the arm on the right rises by $x$ from the eqm value. So the pe on the left drops by $\rho A g x^2$ and the right gains $2 \rho A g x^2$, which makes a net gain of $\rho A g x^2$ with respect to the eqm situation.

Answer (score 1):

Your doubt is common; we should take $2X$ for the change in the potential energy, but potential energy is given by change in the position of C.G. of body, and since it is a uniform, cross-section its C.G. is half of its length i.e. $.5*2X$.
If you are not satisfied, then integrate the potential energy.
You might remember the work done problem as well, where mass of rope is given there we took the $W =mgl/2$ (as rope is uniform cross section).

Comment: Hi Atul, welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. Please use abbreviations consistently for clarity and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write mathematical expressions.

Comment: That referenced helped, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers get to the root of the problem.
Potential energy, here, is not an m.g.h thingy.
The potential energy, here, is the work it took to get the system into its perturbed sate.   Integrate the force, wrt distance, that it took to get it there.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/410768)